# Export table to excel, add "xls" extension to the file

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I'm using this function to export a HTML table to Excel :

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
    })()
```

Everything is working fine, but when the file is created, it create the file as "Unkonw" without any extension, can I add the extension ".xls" somehow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to dynamically create an anchor and download it from there.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var myFileName = 'MyFileName.xls';
a.download = myFileName;
a.setAttribute('href', uri + base64(format(template, ctx)));
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myFileName));
document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(a);
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y0jwhnco/1/

Comment: Hi, when I test your code in jsfiddle, I always have an "Unknown" file, without any extension...